# (Strict) canonical singularity with no crepant resolution

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

We know if a normal singular $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial variety $X$ has a crepant resolution, then it is canonical but not terminal. What can we say about the converse? To be more precise:

Is there a normal singular $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial $X$ which is canonical but not terminal, yet admitting no crepant resolution?

Edit: In light of the first comment, I guess what I really want to ask is if the above situation occurs if $X$ only has one canonical point. (I believe then discrep=0 is achieved by considering a sequence of resolutions with positive discrepancy?)

Comment: Does "resolution" here really mean "resolution" or just "partial resolution"? If the former the answer seems to be "yes" for a fairly trivial reason: let $X$ be a variety with one terminal point and one canonical point.

Comment: That's a good point. I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: If a canonical singularity has a crepant resolution, then it should be Gorenstein. So find a non-Gorenstein canonical singularity is enough for your question. For example with Gorenstein canonical singularities, I think one can produce such example by taking canonical model of a Gorenstein terminal singularity.

Comment: @ChenJiang: why is it that a canonical singularity with a crepant resolution would have to be Gorenstein?

Comment: @SándorKovács: say $Y\to X$ is the crepant resolution such that $K_Y=f^*K_X$, then $K_Y$ is Cartier implies $K_X$ is also Cartier. Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you explain the last step?

Comment: @SándorKovács sorry, I think I made some mistake. I was just thinking if $X$ is projective and $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial then we can get $X$ from $Y$ by running MMP, where we can get $K_X$ is Cartier by using Cone theorem. But clearly it is not the case here.